# Deploying a node js app with proxypass with ssl enabled

Tags: meteor, nginx

I have  ameteor ap which i am running as is the norm and it runs on my server like

http://my-ip:3000

I have nginx installed and i can access the meteor app using this sites-enabled configuration

My file looks like this

```
server {
listen *:80;
server_name _;

location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}
```

I am following this tutorial to get letsencrypt to work https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/a26737699a7e70a7093d4dc115915de8

How would i enable ssl in my configuration above

Answer (score 0):

To run with ssl,make sure you have a letencrypt certificate and this is my configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/meteor.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:3000 https://domain.com;
    }
  }
```

The above runs the meteor app with ssl enabled.